# How to use filter != to exclude rows with either characters within the same column?

Tags: r, filter

I have

```
df %>% filter(column_A != "Char1", column_A != "Char2", column_B != "Char3")
```

which works but doesn't work when I do this

```
df %>% filter((column_A != "Char1" || "Char2"), column_B != "Char3")
```

How do I correct this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for the operator `%in%`

```
df %>% filter(!column_A %in% c("Char1", "Char2"), column_B != "Char3")
```